# How can I bar plot a dataframe with ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, bar-chart

So I'm trying to create a bar plot to represent two different amounts, one representing the amount of transactions made with the coin_type_1 and another to represent the transactions of coin_type_2. As of now, I have this:

```
  montoTipo1 <- df %>%
  group_by(MONEDA, Monto) %>%
  filter(MONEDA=="1") %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  summarise(Monto_Tipo1 = sum(Monto, na.rm = TRUE))

montoTipo2 <- df %>%
  group_by(MONEDA, Monto) %>%
  filter(MONEDA=="2") %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  summarise(Monto_Tipo2 = sum(Monto, na.rm = TRUE))

nombres.MontosTipo <- c("Tipo de moneda 1","Tipo de moneda 2")
montosTipo <- c(montoTipo1[[1]], montoTipo2[[1]])
df.MontosTipo <- data.frame(row.names = nombres.MontosTipo, montosTipo) %>%
  rename("Montos totales" = montosTipo)
```

And the output is:

```
df.MontosTipo
                 Montos totales
Tipo de moneda 1     1617682625
Tipo de moneda 2      248738139
```

How can I plot so in my x axis the "Tipo de moneda" data appear and the values graphed are the values I have in my dataframe?

Comment: Instead of row names, create a column with those names and then run ```ggplot(df.MontosTipo, aes(nombres.MontosTipo, `Montos Totales`)) + geom_col()```.

Comment: Amazing! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RuiBarradas has already pointed out, you want to change the rownames into a column, which we can do with `tibble::rownames_to_column`. Here, I also provide some additional options to further customize the chart. I chose a light hue to fill each bar with. I converted the scientific notation, but if you want the scientific notation along the y-axis, then you can remove the last line here (i.e., `scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)`).

```
library(tidyverse)
require(scales)

df.MontosTipo %>% 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("nombres.MontosTipo") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = nombres.MontosTipo, y = `Montos totales`, fill = factor(`Montos totales`))) + 
  geom_col( ) +
  scale_fill_hue(c = 40) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  xlab("Nombres") +
  ylab("Montos Totales") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma)
```

**Output**

[image]

**Data**

```
df.MontosTipo <-
  structure(
    list(`Montos totales` = c(1617682625, 248738139)),
    row.names = c("Tipo de moneda 1",
                  "Tipo de moneda 2"),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

You could arrive to the same data.frame in a more simple fashion

```
df.MontosTipo <- df %>%
  filter(MONEDA=="2" | MONEDA=="1") %>%
  group_by(MONEDA, Monto) %>%
  group_by(MONEDA) %>% 
  summarise('Montos Totales'= sum(Monto, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
  rename("Tipo de moneda" = "MONEDA")
```

Using your current data.frame and as you already have `tidyverse` then you can run

```
df.MontosTipo <- 
  df.MontosTipo %>% 
  rownames_to_column("Tipo de moneda")
```

Then, as the `Tipo de moneda` is saved in a variable, you can call it inside `ggplot` to your X-axis using the aesthetics mapping.

```
ggplot(df.MontosTipo,
       aes(x = `Tipo de moneda`, y = `Montos Totales`, 
           fill = factor(`Tipo de moneda`))) +
  geom_col()
```

Final thoughts are that is sometimes easier to create variables in the form `var_name` than `var name` so you do not have to add tick marks when calling them inside functions. Also, `geom_bar()` does not accept both X and Y aesthethics so I would rather use `geom_bar()`

[image: Bar plot]

Comment: Amazing, thank you!